# Is it possible to use Django with an Access database?

Tags: django, ms-access

Is it possible to use a Microsoft Access database (.accdb) as the back-end for a Django application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be *possible*, at least under Windows. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/) contains a link to [django-pyodbc](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/), a third-party ODBC back-end that is based on pyodbc, so perhaps you could try using that with the Access ODBC driver for Windows. However, django-pyodbc appears to be coded specifically for Microsoft SQL Server, and the SQL dialects for SQL Server ("T-SQL") and Access ("Access SQL") are similar but not identical, so compatibility with Access SQL may be somewhat limited.

Also, the question remains as to whether it is a *good idea* to use an Access database as a back-end for a Django application. The answer to that question is "Probably not.". An Access database is generally not a good choice of back-end for a web application. In fact, [Microsoft strongly recommends against using Access in web applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database).