# How to connect an MS Access table to become the backend for a django form?

Tags: python, django, database, ms-access, pyodbc

I want to use a MS Access Table as the backend for a django form. I found that there is a django.pyodbc, but having trouble connecting it through there. I also understand this is not the best option, but this is what I have to work with right now plus this is only going to be for internal use. Has anyone successfully connected them can show an example?

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'NAME': '',
        'OPTIONS':{
                'host_is_server':True
        },
    }
}

Comment: That's a terrible idea...but, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251702/how-to-connect-pyodbc-to-an-access-mdb-database-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Django with an Access database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476729/is-it-possible-to-use-django-with-an-access-database)

Comment: While doing that I actually noticed how much of a terrible idea it was. Thank you for the help though.